# php class scope issue

Tags: php, class, oop, scope

I'm having the following issue:
I am creating a visual calendar in php with the following code

```
<?php
class Calendar{

    public $numberOfDays;

    function _construct(){
        $this->$numberOfDays =  cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date("m"), date("Y"));
    } 

public function drawCalendar(){ 

    echo '<div class="month">';
    for( $i=0; $i< $numberOfDays;$i++){     
        echo '<div class="day"></div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';

   }
}
?>
```

The problem is somehow $numberOfDays is not available in the for loop ? And I am getting a Undefined variable: numberOfDays error. What am I doing wrong

Comment: For one thing you forgot an underscore in `_construct()` change it to `__construct()` - [Constructs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) require 2 underscores.

Comment: I learned "2" things today ;-) thanks again @PeeHaa

Comment: I have a broom on my avatar for a reason ;-)

Comment: I can't blame you at all! lol good one @PeeHaa cheers

Comment: thanks all I also forgot that for object references you have to use the $ only for this and not for the to be accessed variable also (bit hard getting back on php after C# :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try....

```
$this->numberOfDays
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
$this->numberOfDays
```

`$this` being a reference to the current object instance